# jQuery - use control pairs

Tags: jquery, selector

I agree the question title is vague, but I could not find a better one.

The problem:

```
    $('[id="SearchSnippetActor"]').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "foo/foo.asmx",
            data: // pass data,
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                // do something
                        label: 'blah blah',
                        val: 'blah blah'
                }))
            },                              
        });
    }, select: function (e, i) {    
                   $('#'+e.target.id).val(i.item.val);
                   $('#DisplaySnippetActor').text(i.item.label);
        return false;
    }
});
```

I'm having these textbox and label pairs. Being an autocomplete, whenever i select a value in the textbox I'm storing "val" in it and "label" in the Label.

It's working fine. The thing is that for each and every pair i've to copy the entire code and replace the textbox/label id's.

Is there anyway to optimize the selector so that i just have to write a single function ?

Example pairs:

DisplaySnippetType : SearchSnippetType
DisplaySnippetText : SearchSnippetText

Thanks,
Dev

Answer (score 0):

You could use class instead of id to assign to all. something like

$('.SearchActorNameClass')....